# fade in, fade out animation to uilabel

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, uilabel

i have a label that i want to fade in and then to fade out. 
here is my code:

```
-(void) fadein
{
    scoreLabel.alpha = 0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    scoreLabel.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
}



-(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished    context:(void *)context {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
 scoreLabel.alpha = 0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

from this code i get this situation: my label is fade in and then i don't see the fadeout animation.
how can i fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
-(void) fadein
{
    scoreLabel.alpha = 0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];

    //don't forget to add delegate.....
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    scoreLabel.alpha = 1;

    //also call this before commit animations......
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}



-(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished    context:(void *)context {
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    scoreLabel.alpha = 0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: thank! i forgot to use setAnimationDelagate, now it work perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

The call to `setAnimationDidStopSelector` should be before commit the animations:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

scoreLabel.alpha = 1;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```